# Mongoengine - Can I get the same document object instance from two subsequent queries?

Tags: python, mongoengine

This is the use case: I have a server that receives instructions from many clients. Each client instructions are handled by its own Session object, who holds all the information about the state of the session and queries mongoengine for the data it needs.

Now, suppose session1 queries mongoengine and gets document "A" as a document object.

Later, session2 also queries and gets document "A", as another separate document object.

Now we have 2 document objects representing document "A", and to get them consistent I need to call A.update() and A.reload() all the time, which seems unnecessary.

Is there any way I can get a reference to the same document object over the two queries? This way both sessions could make changes to the document object and those changes would be seen by the other sessions, since they would be made to the same python object.

I've thought about making a wrapper for mongoengine that caches the documents that we have as document objects at runtime and ensures there are no multiple objects for the same document at any given time. But my knowledge of mongoengine is too rudimentary to do it at the time.

Any thoughts on this? Is my entire design flawed? Is there any easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think going in that direction is a good idea. From what I understand you are in a web application context, you might be able to get something working for threads within a single process but you won't be able to share instances across different processes (and it gets even worse if you have processes running on different machines).

One way to address this is to use optimistic concurrency validation, you basically maintain a field like "version-identifier" that gets updated whenever the instance is updated and whenever you save/update the object, you run a query like "update object if version-identifier=... else you fail"

This means that if there are concurrent requests, 1 of them will succeed (first one to be flusged), the other one will fail because the version-identifier that they have is outdated. MongoEngine has no built in support for that but more info can be found here https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1563